# LearnPython.org Generators trouble

Tags: python, fibonacci

I'm learning python via learnpython.org. I made it through all of the basic classes just fine, but I'm having trouble with the Generators level.

I think I understand how the `yield` command works, but I can't figure out how to use it to get the Fibonacci sequence I need to complete the lesson. Here's my code, but it only gives me the first 2 numbers.

```
# fill in this function
def fib():
    a,b = 1,0  # Sets the values (is this causing a problem?)
    yield a    # Sends back the value of a to the iterator (for loop)
    b = a + b  # Sets the value of b to a + b
    yield b    # Sends back the value of b to the iterator (for loop)

# testing code
import types
if type(fib()) == types.GeneratorType:
    print "Good, The fib function is a generator."

    counter = 0
    for n in fib():
        print n
        counter += 1
        if counter == 10:
            break
```

This is most annoying, as I would like to complete this level, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4):

Your generator will produce one result for each `yield` statement executed. You only executed two `yield` statements, so your generator produced two results.

Try this:

```
def fib():
    a,b = 1,0  # Sets the values (is this causing a problem?)
    while True:
        a,b = b, a + b  # Sets the value of b to a + b
        yield b    # Sends back the value of b to the iterator (for loop)
```

As you can see, the `while` loop will run forever, so this generator will produce an indefinite (infinite?) number of results.

---

Alternatively, you can modify your generator to produce a finite sequence, and modify your caller to take advantage of that:

```
def fib(counter=None, limit=None):
    a,b = 0,1
    i = 0
    while (counter is None or counter > i) and (limit is None or limit > b):
        i += 1
        yield b
        a,b = b, a + b

print list(fib(counter=10))
print list(fib(limit=60))
```

Comment: `Infinite` but limited by the computer's capabilities. `Indefinite` is a better term, no?

Comment: "Indefinite" is clearly the better term. "Infinite" is used more commonly, as in "infinite loop".

Comment: This is very useful. Thanks! One question, however, about the a,b = b,a + b part, how does that work? I thought that a comma (,) would put a space between strings when concatenating and printing, how does this apply to setting the variables (the site says it will simultaneously switch the variables?)

Comment: The comma in a print command is unrelated to this use of comma. The commas in that line indicate the use of [tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). The partial line `... = b, a+b` is an example of *tuple packing*; the other side `a,b = ...` is an example of *tuple unpacking*. The net effect is to assign each value on the right-hand-side to the corresponding name on the left-hand-side.

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is always an implicit `return` at the end of each function. So when your generator reaches the end of the function, after the second yield, it halts. If you want to keep going (an infinite generator) you need to put the yields in an infinite loop.

```
def fib():
    current, past = 1, 0
    while True:
        yield current
        current, past = current + past, current
```

---

Side note:

Also, python has a [nice function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for grabbing the first N items from an infinite generator built in to a cool library called itertools, so the second part could be cleaned up like this:

```
from itertools import islice
for number in islice(fib(), 10):
    print(number)
```